# How to find save user data into profile in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

My initial problem was that I wasn't able to write anything in the enter name slot and it would immediately just go to the previous page when I click on the button done. However, with this new code I can actually type my name in, but it doesn't let me save/the done button doesn't do anything. There's like a warning with NavigationLink and I think I have to use NavigationStack but I've tried different methods here and there but I can't seem to figure out how I can fix the issue.

```
           Button(action: {saveName()
                isDone = true})
            {Image("done").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 103, height: 103)
                    .padding(.leading,259)
                    .padding(.bottom,740)
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: Profile(), isActive: $isDone, label: {EmptyView()}
            )
            .hidden()
        }
    }
    private func saveName() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(profilename, forKey: "User_Name")
    }
}
```

I tried creating a NavigationStack but then the profile items are not individual items rather they're all meant to be part of the same screen so I had no luck following the simple tutorials. I previously tired:

```
  .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $donetapped,onDismiss: didDismiss)
                        Profile()
```

but the problem with this was that it wouldn't let me type anything to the text frame and the moment I clicked on the text box, it would just click done and go back to the previous screen.